# Parametric plot radial Colouring

Tags: plotting, color

I would like to draw a circular segment with a colour gradient based on the radial distance from the center. Currently I have:

```
ParametricPlot[
    {ρ Cos[θ], ρ Sin[θ]}, {ρ, 5, 25}, {θ, π/4, (3 π)/4},
    ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]]],
    Axes -> False, Frame -> False
]
```

which gives the following:

[image]

Which clearly is not coloured according to the radial distance from the centre. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're encountering is due to [`ColorFunctionScaling`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunctionScaling)->[`True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/True). Set it to [`False`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/False), and then normalize your [`Hue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hue) function:

```
ParametricPlot[
    {ρ Cos[θ], ρ Sin[θ]},
    {ρ, 5, 25},
    {θ, π/4, 3 π/4},
    ColorFunction->Function[{x,y},Hue[Sqrt[x^2+y^2]/25]],
    ColorFunctionScaling->False,
    Axes->False,
    Frame->False
]
```

[image]